# Circular references in PowerDesigner

Tags: indexing, sybase, circular-reference, powerdesigner

I'm using sybase to create my database for a school project. After designing my Conceptual Data Model and generating a Physical Data Model, every time I try to generate a database I get an error:

-package  Circular References     Reference 'has a'.Reference 'has a'

-Table Index    Index inclusion Index 'Relationship_6.RELATIONSHIP_6_PK' includes 'RELATIONSHIP_6_FK'     ::Relationship_6

Can someone explain what might be the problem and a proper way to handle it?

After carefully checking my CDM I can't find anything related to the errors given.

Comment: A picture of this part of the model would help... Maybe just showing the PK, references, and FK, around this table...

Comment: It's not related to the problem, but if you are actually generating the tables for Sybase ASE, the PK are auto-indexed, so you don't need to create an index for it.